# How to Connect to existing SQLite Database PhoneGap Application

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I have designed my own SQLite Database by using SQLite Manager in Mozilla WebBrowser
When I am Pushing it to Device, I can see it in File Explorer.
But, I am not getting how to use this pushed database in javascript code.
Whenever I am using

```
window.openDatabase("DBName", "1.0", "New DB Demo", 200000);
```

It creates new databse with the name app_database:DBName

Any idea about why this is happening?

and in LogCat It is giving Error as

```
sqlite returned error code = 14 msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

Please Provide me the Correct Solution